# Как склонить двойное отчество?

Tags: склонение

Моего сына звать Рустам, отчество — Абдул Хабиб. Вопрос: как правильно звучит в родительном падеже отчество ребёнка?

Answer (score 2):

Абдул Хабиб не может быть отчеством. Если это имя отца, то отчество будет Абдул-Хабибович.
Как это написать без дефиса - не представляю, это надо разбираться в ЗАГСе. Но думаю, надо настаивать именно на дефисном написании, это избавит в дальнейшем от многих недоразумений.

Если же ситуация та, что в паспорте ***уже*** стоит это сочетание в графе "отчество" без всякого изменения, то грамматически это будет просто "второе имя". Тогда и склонять надо все составляющие:

Рустам Абдул Хабиб (Ибрагимов)
Рустама Абдула Хабиба (Ибрагимова) - и т. д.